# $scope is not updated after database trigger

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have following controller which is posting a new user and also getting new users.

The problem here  is after adding a new user, the scope is not updated so view is not affected. I have also tired returning the function so it expects a promise but didnt update the scope.

```
myapp.controllers('users', ['usersService', ''$scope',', function(usersService, $scope){

   getUsers();

   function getUsers(params) {
       if (typeof(params) === "undefined") {
             params = {page: 1};
        }

   usersService.getUsers(params).then(function (res) {
        $scope.users = res.items;
        $scope.usersListTotalItems = res._meta.totalCount;
        $scope.usersListCurrentPage = res._meta.currentPage + 1;
    });
        }


   }


 $scope.addUser = function (user) {
        usersService.adddNewUser(user).then(function (response) {

           getUsers();

        });
    }


}]);



myApp.factory('userService', ['Restangular', '$http', function (Restangular, $http) {

return {

    getUsers: function (params) {

        var resource = 'users/';
        var users = Restangular.all(resource);

        return users.getList(params)
            .then(function (response) {
                return {
                    items : response.data[0].items,
                    _meta : response.data[0]._meta
                }
            });
    },

     adddNewUser: function (items) {

        var resource = Restangular.all('users');

        var data_encoded = $.param(items);
        return resource.post(data_encoded, {}, {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}).
            then(function (response) {
                return response;
            },
            function (response) {
                response.err = true;
                return response;
            });
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: what is the code for adddNewUser function ?

Comment: share the code for userService as well...I guess problem may be over there. Also you can change the response of the update call to fetch the list of updated users, instead of making another db call, thats a separate thing but one point which I observed

Comment: @V31 I have added the service part

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a small error however you did not include $scope in the argument for the controller function.

```
myapp.controllers('users', ['usersService','$scope', function(usersService $scope){

   getUsers();

   function getUsers(params) {
       if (typeof(params) === "undefined") {
             params = {page: 1};
        }

   usersService.getUsers(params).then(function (res) {
        $scope.users = res.items;
        $scope.usersListTotalItems = res._meta.totalCount;
        $scope.usersListCurrentPage = res._meta.currentPage + 1;
    });
        }


   }


 $scope.addUser = function (user) {
        usersService.adddNewUser(user).then(function (response) {

           getUsers();

        });
    }


}]);
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while posting question, i have updated the question

Comment: are you getting the response in res variable of the controller?

Comment: when the page loads for the first time, it gets the value but after a new user is created and the same function is called scope is not updated and also the res is the same as it was doing page load

Comment: is the new user getting added?

Comment: I think your error block is getting invoked in the userservices addUser function, because of which getUsers() is not getting called. Can you create a plunkr for the same, as it appears that the code that is their is correct.